# Rails Console App Initialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, initialization, rubygems

I created a new rails app this evening (v. 4.2.5) to do some experimenting within `ActiveRecord` and `ActiveModel`.  I noticed some unexpected behavior when starting/restarting the rails console after modifying some of the gems code.

### Example

1. run `bundle open activemodel` modify a method with a `p` statement, save file. (truncated snippet).

   ```
   def define_proxy_call(include_private, mod, name, send, *extra) #:nodoc:
    p '+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'
   ```
2. open up `rails c` call something that will invoke this method.

   ```
   Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.5)
   2.2.2 :001 >
   2.2.2 :001 > Product.new
   "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
   "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
   "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
   "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
   "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
   "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
   "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
   "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
   "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
   "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
   "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
   "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
   "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
   "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
   "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
   "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
   "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
   "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
   "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
   "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
   "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
   "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
   "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
   "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
   "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
   "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
   "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
    => #<Product id: nil, in_stock: nil, name: nil>
   2.2.2 :002 >
   ```
3. Go back into modified file and comment out my `p` statement, save file.

   ```
   def define_proxy_call(include_private, mod, name, send, *extra) #:nodoc:
    #p '+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'
   ```
4. running `reload!` in rails console and re-calling `Product.new` provides the same output as step 2.  Exiting out of rails console and restarting with `rails c` also give me the same output as step 2.

### Expectation - Question

I expected exiting out of the rails console and re-starting would "re-initialize" the rails loading process (thus reload `ActiveModel`), this doesn't seem to be the case. I found the only way to see the changes reflected was to completely exit my shell.

If someone could please explain why would I have to completely exit the shell in order to see changes I made in a gem reflected? Shouldn't I simply be able to exit/restart the rails console?

I got the impression from skimming the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html) that calling `rails c` would start the boot sequence just like `rails s` Thanks!

Comment: Have you disabled [spring](https://github.com/rails/spring)? You can try to just stop the spring server with `spring stop`. When you exit the shell the spring process would be killed anyway, so that would explain the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: @taglia, yes it was spring.  I actually just removed it from the `Gemfile` and ran `bin/spring binstub --remove --all`.  This was simply for some experimentation on my part. The behavior was as I expected after that.  Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the answer is [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642160/rails-console-app-initialization#comment58966463_35642160)

Comment: Looks like the answer is [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642160/rails-console-app-initialization#comment58966463_35642160). You should be able to close your question.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this setting affecting that behavior:

On config/environments/development.rb

Switch on

```
config.eager_load = true
```